# Loop through a data array variable and select items from multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Created a multi-select dropdown, when I click on any of the options I have a input field which stores the values in a textbox. When the page reloads- I want to reselect the values in the multi-select drop down. The text box keeps its values so i was hoping to loop through this if i put it in an array.

E.g. Text contains: "cheese,mozarella"

It is important to only check the items that have the value in the textbox

Jquery:

```
document.getElementById("txt1").value = "cheese,mozarella";
var data =  document.getElementById("txt1").value;
var dataarray = data.split(","); //splits values (,)

console.log(dataarray);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < dataarray.length; i++) {       
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" runat="server" id="txt1" visible="true" value="0" /> 

<div class="container">
    <select id="basic" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have a codeply to demonstrate: https://www.codeply.com/go/mCcxCM0vHs

My aim is to get some jquery code to loop through a dataarray variable and check the box if the value exists and tick it.

Answer (score 0):

This function receives a `select` and a `value` and will cycle through the `select`'s options, compare to the given `value` and mark matching options as `selected`.

```
function prepopulateOptions(selectElement, value) {
    var options = selectElement.options;
    for (var i = 0, numberOfOptions = options.length; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {

        if (options[i].value == value) {
            options[i].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This function clears all selected options.

```
function clearSelect(selectElement) {
    var options = selectElement.options;
    for (var i = 0, numberOfOptions = options.length; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        options[i].selected = false;
    }
}
```

Then tweak your script:

```
var data = "cheese,mozarella",
    dataarray = data.split(","),
    selectElement = document.getElementById('basic');

// clear select first
clearSelect(selectElement);

for (var i = 0; i < dataarray.length; i++) {
    prepopulateOptions(selectElement, dataarray[i]); 
}
```

**Check the fiddle**
With jQuery this could be rewritten even easier:
https://jsfiddle.net/rtm0n53b/

Comment: On the console it shows the following coming back as 'true' console.log(prepopulateOptions(document.getElementById("basic"), dataarray[i])); but the checkboxes are not checked on the multiselect drop down:

Comment: Still doesnt work. https://www.codeply.com/go/mCcxCM0vHs
Cheese,Mozeralla is stored in the textbox, but its got all values selected in the multiselect dropdown

Comment: I am expecting if the data variable is "Cheese,Mozarella" it checks both of these in the drop down list. If its "Cheese,Mushrooms,Pepperoni" it checks all three of these in the drop down list.

Comment: Boy, no, what you asked for works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rtm0n53b/

Answer (score 0):

Use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnLoadOptions(text){
        //--clear selection
        $('#basic option').prop("selected", false);
        //--load selection
        text = text||'';
        var items = text.split(',');
        for(var i in items) {
            $('#basic option[value="'+items[i]+'"]').prop("selected", true);    
        }
        if($.fn.multiselect!=null) {
            $('#basic').multiselect('refresh'); //--if using the bootstrap multiselect plugin, then refresh it.
        }
    }
    var key = 'checkedOptions';
    //--load previous selection
    var previousSelection = localStorage.getItem(key);
    fnLoadOptions(previousSelection);
    $("#txt1").val(previousSelection);

    //--bind to new selection      
    $('#basic').change(function () {
        var v = $('#basic').val();
        $("#txt1").val(v);
        localStorage.setItem(key,v);
    });
    $('#txt1').bind("keyup change",function () {
        fnLoadOptions($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me - it is not ticking the checkbox values only from the textbox.

Comment: @RA19 do you want to type on the textbox and update the selected options/values based in textbox text?

Comment: This is still not working.

1. As default all checkboxes are checked on page load
2. If I de-select all and select 'onions' as the only option this will update the textbox field to have the value onions.
3. When i refresh the page or click on a button, the dropdown values go back to being all checked and does not keep the previous value 'onions' and checked. The value 'onions' however is still stored in the textbox on page refresh.

I am trying to find a way to set the multiselect drop down to tick the previously set value that is now stored in the textbox.

Comment: Your updated answer is setting the text to onions, and checks everything but 'tomatoes' so this does not work. See: https://www.codeply.com/go/mCcxCM0vHs

Comment: @RA19 I just see you're using an [external plugin for multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect). In this case you need to refresh the multiselect control after any external change by calling the function `refresh`, like this: `$('#basic').multiselect('refresh');` Check my updated answer.